Sumar Diferencia de dias segun el año
Tengo una tabla donde se registran las vacaciones por empleado, en la cual tengo las siguientes columnas
Empl
FechaI
FechaF

Lo que necesito sacar los días de diferencia entre las fechas y sumarlos ya sea por año o por periodo (Del 01-Enero al 30-Junio y del 01-Julio al 31-Dic de cada año)
Ejemplo

La Opción 1 seria sumando por año y la dos por los periodos.
Ojala alguien tenga alguna idea de como poder realizarlo
Lo estoy trabajando en SQLServer

¿Qué pasa si alguien tiene un periodo que abarca desde junio hasta julio? ¿Se divide entre los dos periodos o se asigna a uno?

Suponiendo que ya tienes una consulta que te devuelve las columnas:
Empl
FechaI
FechaF
Dias

Puedes obtener rápidamente el resultado que quieres valiendote de:

La función year() para extraer el año de la fecha
La función datepart() para extraer el trimestre de la fecha
Una sentencia case para partir la información en semestres. En esta construcción, vamos a devolver 1 si el trimestre, obtenido con el paso anterior, es 1 o 2, y 2 en caso contrario (es decir, si es 3 o 4).
La función de ventana sum(), que la vamos a usar dos veces con particiones diferentes:

La primera partición, para sumar los días por año, es por Empleado y año.
La segunda partición, para sumar los días por semestre es por Empleado, año y semestre.



Para hacer accesibles los cálculos, uso el operador cross apply.
Para armar la solución final, metemos tu consulta actual en un CTE y construimos la consulta final sobre este:
;
with 
CalculoDias as (
-- tu consulta actual
)
select   Empl
       , FechaI
       , FechaF
       , Dias
       , sum(Dias) over (partition by Empl, Anio) DiasDelAnio
       , sum(Dias) over (partition by Empl, year(FechaI), Anio, Semestre) DiasDelSemestre
  from CalculoDias
       cross apply ( select   year(FechaI) as Anio
                            , case when datepart(quarter, fechaI) in (1, 2) then 1 else 2 end Semestre
                   ) q1


Con tus datos de prueba, obtengo estos resultados (db-fiddle):
Empl        FechaI     FechaF     Dias        DiasDelAnio DiasDelSemestre
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------------
11204       2022-12-21 2022-12-23 3           8           8
11204       2022-07-25 2022-07-29 5           8           8
11204       2023-04-03 2023-04-05 3           8           3
11204       2023-07-24 2023-07-28 5           8           5
11204       2024-03-25 2024-03-27 3           4           4
11204       2024-03-20 2024-03-20 1           4           4

(6 rows affected)

Finalmente, algunos comentarios sobre tu diseño actual y alguna experiencia sobre este tema:

La solución se basa en la fecha de inicio. Si un empleado gozó un período de vacaciones que abarca dos años o dos semestres distintos, estos días se van a reflejar en el año y en el semestre de inicio del período. Esto puede o no ser aceptable para una organización de la vida real (usualmente no lo será). Por lo que hay un trabajo adicional para detectar esos casos y resolverlos.
En muchos países, la legislación permite gozar fracciones de días de vacaciones, tu diseño no contempla eso.
Usualmente se cuenta como días de vacaciones solo los días hábiles del trabajador, según su jornada laboral. Si un trabajador tiene jornada de lunes a viernes, usualmente solo se cuentan estos días.
Tampoco suelen contar como días de vacaciones los asuetos, feriados y otros festivos que sean de descanso para el trabajador.


Puedes usar un DATEDIFF() para comprar las dos columnas de fecha y utilizar el operador dd, en tu caso yo use este query: select Empl, FechaI, FechaF, DATEDIFF(dd,FechaI,fechaF) as Dias from vacaciones;
Base de datos de ejemplo: https://dbfiddle.uk/5q7dw-L3

Esa parte ya la tiene.
